# HashiCorp Nomad OIDC authentication with nested ListClaimMappings

Tags: authentication, openid, nomad, oidc

I've setup a HashiCorp Nomad server and I want to add an OIDC authentication method.
I've made all preparations on the OIDC provider, added config to Nomad server but I cannot seem to get in `ListClaimMappings` the roles I need to check

For example I get as JWT response from OIDC provider:

```
{
  //****//,
  "resource_access": {
    "Nomad": {
      "roles": [
        "engineering"
      ]
    }
  },
  //****//,
  "groups": [
    "nomad_dev"
  ],
  //****//,
}
```

If I try to add config in Nomad:

```
{
  "OIDCDiscoveryURL": "*****",
  "OIDCClientID": "Nomad",
  "OIDCClientSecret": "*****",
  "OIDCScopes": ["openid", "roles", "email"],
  "BoundAudiences": [],
  "AllowedRedirectURIs": ["****"],
  "ClaimMappings": {},
  "ListClaimMappings": {
    "groups": "groups"
  }
}
```

I am able to add `nomad acl binding-rule create -auth-method=OIDC -bind-type=policy -bind-name=engineering -selector="nomad_dev in list.groups"` and login successfully with `engineering` policy.

But if I want to use the `engineering` role from `resource_access.Nomad.roles` and change the `ListClaimMappings` with a JSON pointer:

```
"ListClaimMappings": {
  "/resource_access/Nomad/roles": "roles"
}
```

The binding rule `nomad acl binding-rule create -auth-method=OIDC -bind-type=policy -bind-name=engineering -selector="engineering in list.roles"` doesn't seem work.

I have tried with `"resource_access.Nomad.roles": "roles"`, `"resource_access.*.roles": "roles"`, nothing seems to work, except the `group`, that list is not nested.

Am I doing something wrong? From HashiCorp documentations they seem to work with JSON Pointers, but no examples whatsoever.